# Web Crawler with breadth first exploration

Tags: web-crawler, breadth-first-search

I need to write a paper about a web crawler and this web crawler explores the links with breadth-first.

I've made a picture in which i demonstrate the way the crawler explores explores.
Is this correct breadth-first exploration?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is breadth first since you are looking at all pages in one 'depth-level' before continuing onto the next.